# Trimming length of a random drawn line in HTML canvas over time

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have the code below that is drawing a continue line on to a canvas. The line is using live input from sliders as seen here [My test page](http://www.devilwah.com/spiro/), this simulates a Spirograph with 3 axis. (**EDIT!** you have to move slider to start)

I want to keep the lines a set length removing the tail as i go, but because the sliders update the line in real time I am not sure how best to do this and i cant simple recalculate the line unless i record the time the values change.

I was thinking that I could store a list of all the point in an array to make up the of the length of line I am interested in and then clear and redraw each time, but this seems like a lot of duplication. it would be an array of several 100 to 1000 points.

I think this is the way to go and just push the old points out the bottom as new ones are calculated but does any one have any better solutions.

```
    // Your code here!
var globalID;
var r1 = 80;
var ang1 = 0;
var ang2 = 0;
var ang3 = 0;
var flag = null;
var x2 = 0;
var y2 = 0

function drawpatten() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("graphicsView");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000FF";


    ctx.beginPath();
    // move the start if the line to the last know point caculated
    ctx.moveTo(x2 + 200, y2 + 200);

    // get current value of sliders and devide the value by 1000 (sliders are -100 to + 100 so this gives a value of 0.1 to 0.0001 for each ajustment of angle)
    S1 = document.getElementById("slider1");
    angm1 = S1.value / 1000;
    S2 = document.getElementById("slider2");
    angm2 = S2.value / 1000;
    S3 = document.getElementById("slider3");
    angm3 = S3.value / 1000;

    // we are only going to draw to screen for each 10 points we caculate, this allows us to have finer resolutions with out the over head of writing to screen so often

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {


    //increments the angle and reset after 360 full circle
    ang1 = ang1 + angm1; 
    ang2 = ang2 + angm2;
    ang3 = ang3 + angm3;
        if (ang1 > 360) { ang1 = ang1 - 360 };
        if (ang2 > 360) { ang2 = ang2 - 360 };
        if (ang3 > 360) { ang3 = ang3 - 360 };

    // caculate the x y cordinates the points on each circle and of sets them 
    x = (Math.cos(ang1) * r1);
    y = (Math.sin(ang1) * r1);
    x1 = (Math.cos(ang2) * r1) + x;
    y1 = (Math.sin(ang2) * r1) + y;
    x2 = (Math.cos(ang3) * r1) + x1;
    y2 = (Math.sin(ang3) * r1) + y1;

    // draws the next sections of the line       
    ctx.lineTo(x2 + 200, y2 + 200);

    }

    // better way to do this but this flag just skips drawing the first time, this is becasue the first step will have a line from 0,0 to first cacualted point) 
    if (flag > 0) {
        ctx.stroke();
     }
    // set flag after first caculate and stroke
    flag = 1

    // recussivaly call function
    globalID = requestAnimationFrame(drawpatten);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, clear all and redraw all every frame.

Keep all your points in an Array, iterate through them to create a new Path at every frame, and draw that.

```js
var r1 = 80;
var ang1 = 0;
var ang2 = 0;
var ang3 = 0;
var points = [];
// the anim loop
function anim()  {
  // push new points
  makepattern();
  // remove old points
  cleanoldies();
  // draw all
  draw();
  // do it again
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
anim();

function cleanoldies() {
  var max_length = slider4.value * 2;
  while(points.length > max_length) {
    points.shift();
  }
}

function draw() {
  //Here we'll only draw
  var canvas = document.getElementById("graphicsView");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000FF";
  // clear all
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // a single Path
  ctx.beginPath();
  // points are stored in a flat array [x, y, x, y, x...]
  for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2)
    ctx.lineTo(points[i], points[i + 1]);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function makepattern() {
  // push new points
  S1 = document.getElementById("slider1");
  angm1 = S1.value / 1000;
  S2 = document.getElementById("slider2");
  angm2 = S2.value / 1000;
  S3 = document.getElementById("slider3");
  angm3 = S3.value / 1000;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ang1 = ang1 + angm1;
    ang2 = ang2 + angm2;
    ang3 = ang3 + angm3;
    if (ang1 > 360) {
      ang1 = ang1 - 360
    };
    if (ang2 > 360) {
      ang2 = ang2 - 360
    };
    if (ang3 > 360) {
      ang3 = ang3 - 360
    };

    var x = (Math.cos(ang1) * r1),
    y = (Math.sin(ang1) * r1),
    x1 = (Math.cos(ang2) * r1) + x,
    y1 = (Math.sin(ang2) * r1) + y,
    x2 = (Math.cos(ang3) * r1) + x1,
    y2 = (Math.sin(ang3) * r1) + y1;

    // store the next sections of the line       
    points.push(x2 + 200, y2 + 200);

  }
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="10" id="slider1"><br>
<input type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="20" id="slider2"><br>
<input type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="10" id="slider3"><br>
<label>length<input type="range" min="0" max="10000" id="slider4" value="300"></label><br>

<canvas id="graphicsView" height="400" width="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi that is a very complete answer! I did not expect the full code thank you very much indeed :) a very nice point to start from.

Comment: Any idea what this glich is? if you go to http://www.devilwah.com/spiro/ (i hav eset the sliders up) you will see a green circle, after about 10 seconds there will be a straight line cut through the circle. If i dont have the line "ang1 = ang1 - 360" it does not happen, its only if i try to roll over the angle so it resets if it goes over 360.

Comment: @DevilWAH `maxLength = nnn.value * 3`. Why 3 ? I did `* 2` because we store x and y in two different slots. Here you'll end up with the y of one point becoming the x of the next one. And if you wish to go in this way, then you can just do `points.length = maxLength * 2`, no need for the while loop.

Comment: Ahh of course! I was changing the value to change the length of the line. I had changed "points.push(x2 + 200, y2 + 200);"" it so it added the point using "ushift" to add it to the start and then just set the length to trim of the end like you say.

Comment: I still get the same issue, and as mentioned it is the line "ang1 = (ang1 + angm1) % 360;" using Mod to roll over the value.  ang3 = ang3 + angm3;
    if (ang1 > 360) {
      ang1 = ang1 - 360
    }; has the same issue. but "ang1 = ang1 + angm1" works fine.

Comment: I finally worked this out with help of a developer friend. Had to change the value 360 to (2 * Pi). Something to do with a rounding issue he had come across in a previous project.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way to do this would be, as you suggest, maintain an array of the line segments, pushing newly calculated segments onto the end of the array, and shifting the oldest segments from the beginning.  Then, paint the old segment white.  This has the side effect of also erasing little bits and pieces of line that shouldn't be erased, but the line moves so fast in your example that it shouldn't be too noticeable.

If that imperfection is not acceptable, then I can't see any other way than to redraw the whole curve every frame.  Painting in HTML canvases is nice because the browser won't update the screen until the frame is completely drawn (so you don't have to worry about managing another framebuffer.)

Comment: Why paint oldest white?

Comment: Because painting it white effectively erases it.  The page has a white background.

Comment: So first, no it won't "erase" it, the canvas background is transparent + it will be part of antialiasing. Then why render it at all? Simply remove the oldest from your array, clear all at every frame, redraw the whole array.

Comment: I just thought reading that you can pop the items off and as you do erase them. this has the benefit of not writing the entire line only deleting the old parts.

Comment: @DevilWAH just clear all and redraw all. Clearing only parts of the canvas is almost always slower.

Comment: I assume drawing a line with 1,000+ points each frame will not be an issue? Suppose i will have to find out :) , thanks for the pointers i did think this would be the way but good to have it confirmed. .

Comment: It would be in interesting experiment to implement both approaches and see which is more efficient.  I would think that just drawing two line segments (one the new and the other the old) would be faster.  But maybe I'm wrong!

Comment: I think it might be Richard, but i get the point that it would leave the canvas with hidden lines (white) it has to keep track of. I can image it might become a memory hog if left running for a time.

Comment: I don't think Canvas keeps track of lines in that manner.  The Canvas element is more like a frame buffer, i.e., an array of pixels, that takes the same amount of memory if it is completely blank or if it contains many colors.  (Maybe I'll ask that as a question.)  But you're right that it would be perfectly effective to erase the line rather than to paint it white.  In fact, that would be better if DevilWAH ever decides to change the color of the background: the code wouldn't have to be adjusted.

Comment: @RichardEllwood I said "clearing parts" to clear part of a path effectively is a consumptive task. Yes, drawing just the new bits will win in a perf test, but clearing parts + drawing new bits, I'd rather bet on clear+redraw all, and for code clarity, there is no comparison.

Comment: By clearing parts, I just mean to draw a line segment (with transparent pixels) that's probably all of about 5 pixels long or so.  That should be exactly as expensive as adding the new line segment, which is also just drawing 5 or 6 pixels.  Clear+redraw all would amount to calculating and painting thousands of pixels.  My money's on the "clearing parts" approach, but open to being proved wrong!